# WordPress homepage does not load properly on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, mobile-website

I am having an issue with the homepage of my WordPress website not loading properly on mobile devices. When I open a web page on a mobile device, the content on the homepage doesn’t display properly until I touch the screen.

i want that the mobile view of the website loads corectly